# difference is the data of queue depth , disk offset, iops, throughput during analysis of blktrace

Tags: ios, linux, blktrace

Traces of the IOS are captured using blktrace and same is being replayed using blkreplay. I want to check the parameters like throughput , queue depth and IOS so we are using the tools like seekwatcher and iowatcher. There is a huge difference in the parameters of the replay. Even there is a difference in disk offset also. why is it so ?

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you are not using a good reply tool with high-fidelity. Try `btreplay` to get more accurate results.